# why does the JLayeredPane on my new computer windows 10 not work when it does on my old computer?

Tags: java, swing

for a game, i currently use JLayeredPane and set the content pane of the JFrame as a JLayeredPane.
The code below works perfectly fine on my old computer.
However, when i installed java on a new computer, JLayeredPane did not work...
Although i can create an instance of it, it cannot interact with a JFrame or do any other things and it keeps giving me "indirectly referenced" error.

this is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.util.*;
class R{
  public static void main(String args[]){
     // creating jframe
    JFrame g = new JFrame();
//creating jlayeredpane
    JLayeredPane g2 = new JLayeredPane();
//attempting to add the jlayeredpane to the frame
    g.setContentPane(g2);
  }
}
```

here is the error message:

```
2 errors found:
File: C:\Users\ryant\Desktop\java\R.java  [line: 10]
Error: The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
File: C:\Users\ryant\Desktop\java\R.java  [line: 10]
Error: The method setContentPane(java.awt.Container) in the type javax.swing.JFrame is not applicable for the arguments (javax.swing.JLayeredPane)
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling on your new computer?  Are you using an IDE that may be configured differently? (i.e. pointing to an older JDK).

Comment: What are the version of java in the two setups? What in your IDE, if any?

Comment: Which line is line 10 (ten) in file `R.java`?